# Trying to restore remote database

Tags: c#, sql, database, restore

I'm trying to restore a .bak file on a remote sql server but i'm getting

```
Cannot open backup device .bak Operating system error 21(The device is not ready.). RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.
```

This is what i tried

```
 var restore = new Restore();
            restore.Database = databaseName;
            restore.Action = RestoreActionType.Database;
            restore.Devices.AddDevice(backUpFilePath, DeviceType.File);
            restore.ReplaceDatabase = true;
            restore.NoRecovery = false;

            var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
            var serverConnection = new ServerConnection(sqlConnection);

            var sqlServer = new Server(serverConnection);
            restore.SqlRestore(sqlServer);
```

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. (To get better attention. This is a product specific issue, not even SQL language related.)

Comment: The error message seems to be saying that it thinks ".bak" is a backup device. That's what I'd look at first. (`restore.Devices.AddDevice(...)`)

Answer (score -1):

I believe the error message is quite vague, in that it can mean a number of different things.

Are you able to restore that .bak outside of your application in SQL Server? Do the SQL Error logs give any more specific information?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Use the "add a comment" link in the question to leave a comment or to ask for clarification.

Comment: You have to have 50 reputation to do that.... that seems like an illogical way of working.